# Python TypeError: _vhstack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pycharm, hstack

I'm writing a code so that I can extract from acceleration data (matrix 32768x5651) only the energetic windows of interest. I tried to run this code with only 2 columns (idx_col in range(2)) and it worked, but if I substitute 2 with 5651 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\snn\main.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\snn\main.py", line 41, in main
    np.hstack(sig_w, sig_temp)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in hstack
TypeError: _vhstack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How can I solve? I think the sintax is correct, and this is the code I'm using:

```
def main():
    # ---------------------- Load data from sensor 2
    sensor2 = scio.loadmat(r"sensor2.mat")
    data = sensor2['data_sensor2']

    DataSize = data.shape

    # ----------------------- Extract only energetic windows
    # Set threshold
    th = 0.004
    # Observation window length
    winLen = 30
    # Sampling frequency [Hz]
    Fs = 50

    sig_w = np.zeros(2 * winLen * Fs)
    sig_w = sig_w.T
    plt.figure()

    for idx_col in range(5651):
        idx_w = 0
        for idx_row in range(DataSize[0]):
            while idx_row < 32768:
                if data[idx_row, idx_col] < th:
                    idx_row = idx_row + 1
                else:
                    if idx_row < winLen * Fs:
                        sig_temp = (data[0:idx_row + winLen * Fs, idx_col])
                        np.hstack(sig_w, sig_temp)
                    else:
                        # print('sono nel loop')
                        sig_temp = data[idx_row - winLen * Fs:idx_row + winLen * Fs, idx_col]
                        sig_w = np.vstack((sig_w, sig_temp))
                        idx_w = idx_w + 1
                        idx_row = idx_row + winLen * Fs
                        # plt.plot(sig_temp)
                        # plt.show()
                        # plt.xlabel('Time samples')
                        # plt.ylabel('acc')

            if idx_row >= 32768:
                break

    sig_w = sig_w.T
```

Comment: @CristiFati  I tried and I still get this other error File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in hstack
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\snn\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 345, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Comment: OK, then there are more errors in your code (besides `np.hstack((sig_w, sig_temp))`). Probably going through the documentation would be the 1st thing you should do.

Comment: But why does it work with 8 columns for example but with 5000 it gives me error? I don't understand